# Change params value on model callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

So I have 3 models `group`, `recipient` and `group_recipients`.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :group_recipients, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :recipients, through: :group_recipients
end

class GroupRecipient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipient, inverse_of: :group_recipients, autosave: true
    belongs_to :group
end

class Recipient < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :group_recipients, inverse_of: :recipient, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :group_recipients
end
```

Controller#update `recipients_controller.rb`

```
def update
 @recipient = Recipient.with_deleted.find(params[:id])
 if @recipient.update(recipient_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    redirect_url = params[:commit] == 'Save and add another' ? new_recipient_path : edit_recipient_path(@recipient)
    format.html { redirect_to redirect_url, notice: 'Recipient was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render json: {status: :success} }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json do
      render json: {
        status: :error,
        recipient: @recipient,
        errors: @recipient.errors
      }
    end
  end
end
end

 def recipient_params
   params.require(:recipient).permit(
   :email_address, :first_name, :last_name, :language_id,
   :phone, group_ids: [])
 end
```

On recipient `update`, `params[:group_ids]` is received. Here, on `before_update` callback I want to be able to change the `group_ids` value with some logic. I might have to add or remove data from `group_ids` array.

The problem is activerecord updates all the groups according to `params[:group_ids]` even if I change it. It doesnot matter if I use it in before or after callback. Once I set the values in `self.group_ids`, it does make those changes but once the transaction completes, it again revert those changes.

Comment: Please share the controller method.

Comment: @RipTheJacker I have added the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of doing an update in callback before_update is not good, you will encountered problem with recursive error. Another way is to change the params according to your logic in controller, and then you can use a normal update method .

Comment: yes but i don't want to update in callback. I want to just assign the value in model callback.

Comment: You can assign attribute in callback like this . 

```before_update :function_name

def function_name
  self.attribute = something
end```

Comment: This does work, but once the transaction is complete, it gets reverted back.